# How to click on the login button of the CRM application through Selenium and Java?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, geckodriver

This is a simple login which I am doing and Submit button is not getting clicked. However there is no error message in the console and the test shows Passed. I am scripting using BDD framework-cucumber. Please help to resolve this.

Note: after landing on the page, chat window pops up.

URL: https://www.freecrm.com/index.html

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-small" xpath="1">


    @Given("^user is on login page$")
public void user_is_on_login_page() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\mamtha\\Selenium Practice\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com");
}

@When("^user logs in with valid username and password$")
public void user_logs_in_with_valid_username_and_password() throws Exception  {
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxx");       
}

@Then("^user clicks on login button$")
public void user_clicks_on_login_button() {
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click;", login);
}
```

Comment: `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click;", login);` i think it should be `...click()...`

Comment: I had tried with .click() as well. same issue. Test passes and button doesn't get clicked

Comment: Do not post user credentials into your codes. Check your code for confidential material before copy pasting.

Comment: Thanks @SteroidKing666. Noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your `executeScript` method, it should be (Note, you were missing the parenthesis after `click`) -

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", login);
```

Also, you don't really need `JavascriptExecutor`, following code works! (Tested on latest firefox driver and Firefox browser) -

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
login.click();
```

Cross check that you have included the step "user licks on login button" in your feature file.

Comment: Thanks @Shivam Mishra     JavascriptExecutor ,worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavascriptExecutor here. Use CSS. Here you can use the following:

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn-small"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *website* `https://www.freecrm.com/index.html` the element with text as **Login** is within a `<form>` tag. So as an alternative to `click()` method you can also use the `submit()` method as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com");
  driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("naveenk");
  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Test@123");  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-small' and @type='submit']")).submit();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: logged_in]